# Finding the position of an arbitrary object in a static image?

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, image-preprocessing

One common object detection scenario involves finding trained models in an arbitrary scene. For example, we can train a model to understand what a "bicycle" looks like, by providing various images of bicycles we've seen in the past. Then, we can check an arbitrary scene of a busy intersection to determine if it includes anything like our "bicycle."

I'm trying to achieve **the exact opposite**. In this problem, I have a static scene, like this:

[image: A static scene]

Now, I'm trying to see if there is anything similar in the scene, by providing images like the one below. I may provide infinitely many "test" images, and I don't know anything about their content, ahead of time:

[image: A test image that may exist within scene]

In this case, there should be a near-100% match, since the test image is literally cut from the scene.

In the general case, if there is any *reasonable close* match in the image, I'd like to know its position, and a confidence interval:

```json
{
  "matches": [
    {
      "id": "first_match",
      "bounds": [
        {
          "x": 345,
          "y": 955
        },
        {
          "x": 370,
          "y": 1000
        }
        {
          "x": 400,
          "y": 800
        }
      ],
      "confidence": "0.1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Or, represented visually, the match from this example would occur here:

[image: Location of match in original scene]

I have looked at a few tools, like Amazon Rekognition. However, Rekognition is primarily focused on solving the inverse problem (given some trained models, do they exist in an arbitrary scene)?

What approaches or tools can I use to solve this problem?